# setting random localnotifications on iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, notifications, uilocalnotification

I am trying to find a way to schedule random local notifications on the iphone.  I would like to be able to send the user a random message (picked from a list of messages) at a random time during the day, everyday.

I can probably calculate a bunch of random times and messages and just schedule it for the next say 30 days or more, but that seems messy and doesn't allow a good way for the user to be able to cancel the alerts.

My research shows that cron jobs are not supported on the iphone , so it seems I can't just schedule a background process to keep randomizing the notifications, right?
I have also looked into push notifications as another possibility.

However, I wanted to put my question out there to see if you experts had any other ideas.

thanks!

Comment: Hello,you got solution for this question ? if yes, than please share it.

Comment: I wouldn't call it a solution , just a workaround.   I scheduled a bunch of local notifications, I think the limit is around 60.  Then every time the user goes to app from the local notif message, I go ahead and schedule some more (I first check to see how many I can schedule first) by adding the didReceiveLocalNotification method in app delegate.  Let me know if you would like more info on that.

Comment: Here is the solution I ended up using http://iphonediscoveries.blogspot.com/2013/11/renewing-uilocalnotifications.html